# Instance match throws Constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type error

Tags: scala, class, design-patterns, case, matching

I'm building a parse library that has functions with differing parameter requirements and am modeling as follows. The compiler throws the "constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type" error on the match.

Not sure why

```
  class InstructionType[+A](name: String, params: Int) {
    def paramCount = params

    def executeInstruction[A](params: String*) = {
      this match {
        case OneParam(_, fn) => fn(Register(params(0)))
        case TwoParamRegRef(_, fn) => fn(Register(params(0)), isValue(params(0)))
        case TwoParamRefRef(_, fn) => fn(isValue(params(0)), isValue(params(0)))
      }
    }
  }

  case class OneParam(name: String, fn: Register => Unit) extends InstructionType[Register => Unit](name,1) {
    def getInstruction = fn
  }

  case class TwoParamRegRef(name: String, fn: (Register, Either[Register, Int]) => Unit) extends InstructionType[(Register, Either[Register, Int]) => Unit](name,2) {
    def getInstruction = fn
  }

  case class TwoParamRefRef(name: String, fn: (Either[Register, Int], Either[Register, Int]) => Unit) extends InstructionType[(Either[Register, Int], Either[Register, Int]) => Unit](name,2) {
    def getInstruction = fn
  }
```

Comment: I worked around this by using the object pattern using a signature that takes the instruction as a a parameter: `def executeInstruction[A](ins: Instruction[A], params: String*)`

Comment: Doing `(this: Any) match {...}` works, possibly because `OneParam`, etc. are possible subtypes of `Any`

Comment: I think the main problem is you are trying to define cyclic reference in classes.
`class InstructionType` reference to his heirs `OneParam`, `TwoParamRegRef`, `TwoParamRefRef `.

Comment: @BorisAzanov is probably right, because if you move `def executeInstruction[A](instructionType: InstructionType[A], params: String*)` (adding one parameter) to somewhere else it will work